# How to disable the new Opera Alt+Space “quick search”?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, opera, window-manager, accessibility

After a recent update of ChrOpera, pressing Alt+Space no longer gets you the system menu:[image: Screenshot of a Notepad widows with the window management menu opened, captioned “I wanted this”, and what appears to be a gadget for searching with Google, captioned “I got this”. The captions are hand-made with Stack Exchange Freehand Circles™.]
This violates not only the [Microsoft User Interface Principles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728831(v=vs.85).aspx), but also the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and the [Americans with Disabilities Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990) by making it impossible to move the Opera window using only the keyboard.

(Incidentally, this search box also violates explicit user choice by forcing the search engine to be Google)

How to get back the system menu for window management?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [configure your shortcuts](http://help.opera.com/opera/Windows/2393/en/fasterBrowsing.html#keyboard) to free the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> combination in Opera.

> 1. From the main menu, select Settings.
> 2. Click Browser on the sidebar.
> 3. Under Shortcuts, click the Configure Shortcuts button.

Comment: Is there a way to just change the default search engine for the quick search?

Comment: As a peanut gallery comment, this search bar (and the relevant `Open and Close Instant Search` hotkey settings under Shortcuts) apply to Opera 53+ at the moment (i.e. these do not exist on Opera 52 and below).

Answer (score 1):

From Opera 54+, you can disable Quick search or Instant search (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) feature from Settings (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). In order to bring back native system menu too, you have to disable the keyboard shortcut as specified by `0XX0` [here](https://superuser.com/a/1319871/412139).

[image: Setting for Instant search screenshot]

Comment: Downvoted because just turning off this switch does not bring back system menu (which is the main reason one would disable this) — one still needs to disable the shortcut in keyboard settings.

Comment: @kinokijuf, hope the edited answer helps about system menu. Many people may reach here just to disable quick search like I did.